# Truncate text floating around image

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow

I am struggling with an HTML/CSS layout problem.

I need to create a dynamic component that displays the contents of a news story, my goal would be to get a predefined size (in height) component that contains title, image, text and author. The image will need to be placed on the left and the text floating around it.

Given the fixed height of the container I would like the text to be truncated with ellipsis (...) instead of overflowing its div or suddenly breaking off

What I get are the following two versions that differ only in having added the property "overflow:clip;" to the article-content class:

[image: with "overflow: clip;"]

[image: without "overflow: clip;"]

How can I get the ellipsis?

I attach an example: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/71re38uz/52/)

```css
.article {
    height: 220px;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.article-image {
margin: 10px;
  float: left;

}

.article-content {
    overflow:clip;
}

.article-text {
text-align: justify;
margin: 5px;
height:160px;
    
}

.article-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.article-author {
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
 <div class="article">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/250x125?text=Article-Image" class="article-image" alt="" width="250px" height="125px"/>
    <div class="article-content">
    <div class="article-title">
    Article TITLE
    </div>
      <p class="article-text">Dolor amet elit exercitation aliquip. Enim reprehenderit excepteur dolore do exercitation pariatur exercitation occaecat officia qui pariatur aliqua qui. Ad commodo ut ipsum ea tempor excepteur labore exercitation magna. Mollit commodo ullamco magna ipsum ullamco est minim. Qui reprehenderit cillum cillum aute consequat voluptate minim excepteur.
      Dolor amet elit exercitation aliquip. Enim reprehenderit excepteur dolore do exercitation pariatur exercitation occaecat officia qui pariatur aliqua qui. Ad commodo ut ipsum ea tempor excepteur labore exercitation magna. Mollit commodo ullamco magna ipsum ullamco est minim. Qui reprehenderit cillum cillum aute consequat voluptate minim excepteur.
      Dolor amet elit exercitation aliquip. Enim reprehenderit excepteur dolore do exercitation pariatur exercitation occaecat officia qui pariatur aliqua qui. Ad commodo ut ipsum ea tempor excepteur labore exercitation magna. Mollit commodo ullamco magna ipsum ullamco est minim. Qui reprehenderit cillum cillum aute consequat voluptate minim excepteur.
      Dolor amet elit exercitation aliquip. Enim reprehenderit excepteur dolore do exercitation pariatur exercitation occaecat officia qui pariatur aliqua qui. Ad commodo ut ipsum ea tempor excepteur labore exercitation magna. Mollit commodo ullamco magna ipsum ullamco est minim. Qui reprehenderit cillum cillum aute consequat voluptate minim excepteur.
         Dolor amet elit exercitation aliquip. Enim reprehenderit excepteur dolore do exercitation pariatur exercitation occaecat officia qui pariatur aliqua qui. Ad commodo ut ipsum ea tempor excepteur labore exercitation magna. Mollit commodo ullamco magna ipsum ullamco est minim. Qui reprehenderit cillum cillum aute consequat voluptate minim excepteur.
            Dolor amet elit exercitation aliquip. Enim reprehenderit excepteur dolore do exercitation pariatur exercitation occaecat officia qui pariatur aliqua qui. Ad commodo ut ipsum ea tempor excepteur labore exercitation magna. Mollit commodo ullamco magna ipsum ullamco est minim. Qui reprehenderit cillum cillum aute consequat voluptate minim excepteur.Dolor amet elit exercitation aliquip. Enim reprehenderit excepteur dolore do exercitation pariatur exercitation occaecat officia qui pariatur aliqua qui. Ad commodo ut ipsum ea tempor excepteur labore exercitation magna. Mollit commodo ullamco magna ipsum ullamco est minim. Qui reprehenderit cillum cillum aute consequat voluptate minim excepteur.Dolor amet elit exercitation aliquip. Enim reprehenderit excepteur dolore do exercitation pariatur exercitation occaecat officia qui pariatur aliqua qui. Ad commodo ut ipsum ea tempor excepteur labore exercitation magna. Mollit commodo ullamco magna ipsum ullamco est minim. Qui reprehenderit cillum cillum aute consequat voluptate minim excepteur.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article-author">
    Autor Name
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected behavior using css property `line-clamp`.

Add below code inside `.article` class

```
overflow: hidden;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 4;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

This would show ellipsis before line-clamp value.

PS: update `-webkit-line-clamp` value accordingly.

Comment: This way I will have 4 fixed rows, my goal is to keep it dynamic and depending only on container's height

Comment: You have mentioned in your question - "Given the fixed height of the container I would like the text to be truncated with ellipsis (...) instead of overflowing its div or suddenly breaking off". If you want to keep it dynamic, you can calculate the general value of lines and set line-clamp value dynamically with javascript.

Comment: I confirm what I wrote but fixed height does not mean constant number of rows because the container varies in width in various situations.

Comment: I also thought about the javascript solution but it seems too much effort and waste of resources to only get three dots at the end of the text